# How to get a list of the implement rules - FluentValidations

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, asp.net-web-api-helppages

Using [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) with WebAPI, I am attempting to show the rules that are implemented on a property.

I am using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage assemblies that will generate the help pages for my API. I would like to be able to enumerate the validation rules so I can display the attributes like required and the length on my help pages.

Previously, I would do this for a custom attribute with something like the following:

```
-- namespace MyAPI.Areas.HelpPage.ModelDescriptions

private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<object, string>> AnnotationTextGenerator =
    new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>
    {
        { typeof(MyAttribute), a => "My Attribute Documentation" }
    };
```

This would add the text required in the additional information section of the help page. In the event of using [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation), the required type is no longer set. It is now something like `RuleFor(x => x.MyProperty).NotEmpty();`

If helpful, the code that is documenting the annotations is below:

```
-- namespace MyAPI.Areas.HelpPage.ModelDescriptions
/// <summary>   Generates the annotations. </summary>
/// <param name="property">         The property. </param>
/// <param name="propertyModel">    The property model. </param>
private void GenerateAnnotations(MemberInfo property, ParameterDescription propertyModel)
{
    var annotations = new List<ParameterAnnotation>();

    var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes();
    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        Func<object, string> textGenerator;
        if (AnnotationTextGenerator.TryGetValue(attribute.GetType(), out textGenerator))
        {
            annotations.Add(
                new ParameterAnnotation
                {
                    AnnotationAttribute = attribute,
                    Documentation = textGenerator(attribute)
                });
        }
    }

    // Rearrange the annotations
    annotations.Sort(
        (x, y) =>
        {
            // Special-case RequiredAttribute so that it shows up on top
            if (x.AnnotationAttribute is RequiredAttribute)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (y.AnnotationAttribute is RequiredAttribute)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            // Sort the rest based on alphabetic order of the documentation
            return String.Compare(x.Documentation, y.Documentation, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        });

    foreach (var annotation in annotations)
    {
        propertyModel.Annotations.Add(annotation);
    }
}
```

When calling this GenerateAnnotations routine I would like to add the logic that will look at the property and get all the fluent attributes assigned and add the text.

Maybe somehow use the [FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRules](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/Internal/PropertyRule.cs) to elegantly enumerate the attributes?